# Disabling on screen keyboard

Tags: j2mepolish

I'm working on a j2me application and i'm using j2me polish. when i deploy the application on any touch screen devices like Nokia N97 / Samsung Omnia the on-screen keyboard comes by default. I need to go to the installed applications and disable it everytime i install the applicaton. Is there any way by adding some property in the build.xml to disable the on-screen keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

got the solution, add the following property in in jad name="Nokia-MIDlet-On-Screen-Keypad" value="no"

Answer (score 0):

I found the Answer, the jad property is

Navi-Key-Hidden: true for SAMSUNG devices.